# Ordered Binary Search w/ Assembly | Recursive vs. Iterative vs. Library

Tags: c++

Which is better?

According to Savitch, each recurse is saved on the stack in the form of an activation frame.  This has overhead.  However it takes a few less lines of code to write a recursive version.  For an interview which one is better to turn in.  The code for both is below.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
const int SIZE = 10;
int array[ SIZE ] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
int answer = NULL;

void binary_search_recursive( int array[], int start, int end, int value, int& answer )
{
    int mid = (start + end ) / 2;

    if ( array[ mid ] == value )
    {
        answer = mid;
    }
    else if ( array[ mid ] < value )
    {
        binary_search_recursive( array, mid + 1, end, value, answer );
    }
    else
    {
        binary_search_recursive( array, start, mid - 1, value, answer );
    }
}

void binary_search_iterative( int array[], int start, int end, int value, int& answer )
{
    int mid = ( (start + end ) / 2 );

    while( array[ mid ] != value  )
    {
        if ( array[ mid ] < value )
        {
            start = mid; 
            mid = ( ( ( mid + 1 ) + end ) / 2 );
        }
        else
        {
            end = mid;
            mid = ( ( start + ( mid - 1 ) ) / 2 );
        } 
    }
    answer = mid;
}

int main()
{
    binary_search_iterative( array, 0, SIZE - 1, 4, answer);
    cout << answer;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I believe it fits better to [codereview.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), though not perfectly..

Comment: What happens with your code when you search for an element not in the array? I think you may be missing another exit condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an interview, I'd start by mentioning that both recursive and iterative solutions are possible and similarly trivial to write.  Recursive versions have a potential issue with nested stack frames using or even exhausting stack memory (and faulting different pages into cache), but compilers tend to provide tail recursive optimisations that effectively create an iterative implementation.  Recursive functions tend to be more self-evidently correct and concise, but aren't as widely applicable in day to day C++ programming so may be a little less familiar and comfortable to maintenance programmers.

Unless there's a reason not to, in a real project I'd use `std::binary_search` from `<algorithm>` (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/binary_search.html).

To illustrate tail recursion, your binary_search_recursive algorithm was changed to the assembly below by `g++ -O4 -S`.  Notes:

- to get an impression of the code, you don't need to understand every line, but the following helps:

  - `movl` are move statements (assignments) between registers and memory (the trailing "l" for "long" reflects the number of bits in the registers/memory locations)
  - `subl`, `shrl`, `sarl`, `cmpl` are subtraction, shift right, shift arithmetic right, and compare instructions, and the important thing to note is that as a side effect they set a few flags, such as "equals" if they produce a 0 result, that is consulted by `je` (jump if equals) and `jge` (jump if greater or equal), `jne` jump if not equal.
- the `answer = mid` termination condition is handled at L10, while the recursive steps are instead handled by the code at L14 and L4 and may jump back up to L12.

Here's the disassembly of your binary_search_recursive function (the name is mangled in C++ style)...

```
__Z23binary_search_recursivePiiiiRi:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %edi
    pushl   %esi
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $4, %esp
    movl    24(%ebp), %eax
    movl    8(%ebp), %edi
    movl    12(%ebp), %ebx
    movl    16(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    %eax, -16(%ebp)
    movl    20(%ebp), %esi
    .p2align 4,,15
L12:
    leal    (%ebx,%ecx), %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    shrl    $31, %eax
    leal    (%edx,%eax), %eax
    sarl    %eax
    cmpl    %esi, (%edi,%eax,4)
    je      L10
L14:
    jge     L4
    leal    1(%eax), %ebx
    leal    (%ebx,%ecx), %edx
    movl    %edx, %eax
    shrl    $31, %eax
    leal    (%edx,%eax), %eax
    sarl    %eax
    cmpl    %esi, (%edi,%eax,4)
    jne     L14
L10:
    movl    -16(%ebp), %ecx
    movl    %eax, (%ecx)
    popl    %eax
    popl    %ebx
    popl    %esi
    popl    %edi
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .p2align 4,,7
L4:
    leal    -1(%eax), %ecx
    jmp     L12
```

Comment: this is why I prefer compiled languages to scripting languages

Answer (score 4):

Recursive versions of algorithms are *often* shorter in lines of code but iterative versions of the same algorithm are *often* faster because of the function call overhead of the recursive version.

Regarding the binary search algorithm, the faster implementations are written as iterative. For example Jon Bentley's published version of the binary search is iterative.

Comment: The recursive version he wrote is tail-recursive so it could be optimised to code that is as fast as the iterative version.

Comment: @SethCarnegie agree, but as tail call elimination is not mandatory in C like in Scheme or Haskell, at least with the iterative one you are in the safe side for performances :)

Comment: @GuyMontag tail recursion is when a recursive function calls itself _as the very last thing it does_. When a function is tail-recursive, the compiler can optimise it so that it doesn't do a function call but a jump, which makes a tail-recursive function as short as a recursive function and as fast as an iterative function. [See Wikipedia for more details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Tail-recursive_functions).

Comment: @ouah that is true, so if you definitely want to be safe, then I agree, go iterative. However, almost all modern compilers will do this tail call optimisation on higher optimisation levels.

Answer (score 2):

In case of a binary search recursion does not help you express your intent any better than the iteration does, so an iterative approach is better.

I think the best approach for an interview would be to submit a solution that calls [`lower_bound`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/lower_bound.html): it shows the interviewer that you not only know some basic-level syntax and how to code a freshman-year algorithm, but that you do not waste time re-writing boilerplate code.

Comment: @GuyMontag Back in the day, SGI STL was perhaps the most popular STL implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You use iteration if speed is an issue or if the stack size is constraining, because as you said it involves calling the function repeatedly which results in it occupying more space on the stack. As for answering in the interview I would go for whichever I feel is simplest to do correctly at that time, for obvious reasons :))